# SublimeText3: How to do the the opposite of `focus_side_bar`, i.e. focus the main view?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I have a command in a sublime plugin

```
v.window().run_command("reveal_in_side_bar")
v.window().run_command("focus_side_bar")
```

that focuses the sidebar. And in another command I hide the side bar (by `toggle_side_bar`) but the focus still remains on the (now hidden) sidebar.

How to switch the focus back to the main view (the file contents)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sublime.Window`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.Window) has several methods that could be useful, including `focus_view(view)`, `active_view()`, `focus_group(group)`, and `active_group()`. You can save the current view with `active_view()`, run your `reveal_in_side_bar` and `focus_side_bar` commands, then switch back to the formerly active view with `focus_view()`. Or, if you only have one group in your window, `focus_group(0)` will switch back to it. If there are multiple groups, use `active_group()` to get its index.

Answer (score 1):

Press Escape key while in the side-bar would return you to the main edit